# automatic generated XML sitemap for Weblication

Tags: xml, content-management-system, seo, search-engine, sitemap

Is there a Weblics for Weblication 4.8.14 which automatically generates the XML sitemap for Google?

I found a Weblic called "Sitemap 2.0.5", but the [demo](http://classic.wdemo.de/wDeutsch/sitemap/) only shows a sitemap for the user in a php file. I would need a sitemap.xml. Is that possible? Or do I have to generate one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that is only possible for Grid (v. 5+). You can yourself write a script which reads out the navigation and creates a XML file. Or you do it manually (Google tools).